# Back to main view controller from modal View controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, viewcontroller, ios5.1

I want to make a back button from a modal view to the Main view.

The View Controller is embedded in the navigation controller. The menu button take me to the Second View Controller. There I have a back button who works fine using this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I want to go back to the Main View Controller from the Page Two VC.

I have tried:

```
- (IBAction)goToRootView:(id)sender {

[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:(NO) completion:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and:

```
- (IBAction)goToRootView:(id)sender {


[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:(NO) completion:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The first just goes back to the Second VC, the last sends and lldb error.

How can I go from Mantras Page Two VC to Main VC?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tray this...

```
CHS_View_Controller *oldView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CHS_View"];
UINavigationController *yourNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:oldView];

yourNavigationController.modalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:yourNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

for that you must:

1) import you dest controller

```
#import "CHS_View_Controller.h" // your controller name
```

and

2)
set an Identifier for your CHS_Controller, "CHS_View" in the bellow example (into the Storyboard Editor and in the Attributes Inspector)

Comment: I have tried your snippet but this error comes out:

2013-01-25 12:44:30.010 Chingosound[2476:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: `- (IBAction)goToRootView:(id)sender {
    
    chsViewController *oldView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chs_view_controller"];
    UINavigationController *mantrasPageTwoViewController= [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:oldView];
    
    mantrasPageTwoViewController.modalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    
    [self presentViewController:mantrasPageTwoViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}`

Comment: Don't use for NavigationController a name identical with one of your VierController - can "colide". Use any other name : UINavigationController *navig", "navC", etc -

Comment: From my example, You have to modify just first line. The rest... Can use it untouched

Comment: It works now, but it returns me to the main menu with the Nav bar enabled (I have it disabled), maybe I should hide it programmatically?

Comment: very easy, you must add next line:     [yourNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, instead of

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

try

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Still not working, it takes me to the Mantras View Controller instead of the Root VC